# How to configure manifest version in parent pom so that it reflects the child modules

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

How to configure manifest version in parent pom so that it reflects the child modules.

My project parent pom has five child modules which are jars.
I want to configure parent pom with manifest version so that each child jar has that manifest version.
How should i configure in parent pom.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to put the following [archiver configuration](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestEntries.html) into for example the maven-jar-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Manifest-Version>2.0</Manifest-Version>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This archive configuration must be repeated for the different plugins like war, ear, ejb if you are using them. The solution is to put such thing into the pluginManagement part of your parent pom. In your described case you need to put the above configuration into the pluginManagement part of your parent.